# Calculate number of days remaining

Tags: php, date, days

I would like to calculate the number of days remaining before a date. In my database I have a timestamp corresponding to the end date. For example Friday 30. I would like to say something like that :

7 days remaining... 6, 5, 4, etc

Can you help me please ?

Comment: I forgot to say that my end date is a timestamp.

Comment: What's wrong with floor(($endTimestamp - time()) / 86400); ?

Comment: Storing timestamps in a database is not good practice. Your DBMS will provide data types which better suits dates.

Comment: What type I should use ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$future = strtotime('21 July 2012'); //Future date.
$timefromdb = //source time
$timeleft = $future-$timefromdb;
$daysleft = round((($timeleft/24)/60)/60); 
echo $daysleft;
```

Comment: Edited. Future should be the date you are **counting down to**

Comment: This doesn't go into negatives.

Answer (score 10):

```
  $date1 = new DateTime("2016-01-01");  //current date or any date
  $date2 = new DateTime("2016-12-31");   //Future date
  $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");  //find difference
  $days = intval($diff);   //rounding days
  echo $days;
  //it return 365 days omitting current day
```

Comment: Best solution, choose this for Y2K38.

Comment: Just a question, if the date already passed the returned value is negative?

Answer (score 5):

```
$days = round((timestamp_from_database - time()) / 86400);
```

Comment: @BobbaFett What returns a timestamp? `$days` should be number of days, I'm pretty sure of it.

Comment: This one works the best, just use `strtotime()` for the timestamp

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yourtimestamp, CURDATE()) AS days
```

doc ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score -1):

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date-diff.php

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_date_diff

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  It's also better to edit your answer as people don't always read the comments.